Getting a list of all countries to using npm countries-list
I have installed the package: npm install countries-list
This contains:
Module exports continents, countries, languages and utility functions.
if I do
import { continents, countries, languages } from 'countries-list'
and do
console.log(countries), I get an array containing all the countries, capital, continent etc.
So fx, I want to create dropdown box where I populate it with countries.
If I do
for (let i=0; i < countries.length; i++) { console.log(countries[i]) }

I get undefined. Hence I can't do countries[i].name etc. I also tried doing
 countries.forEach((val) => {
...
{)

which also gives an error. If I want to get a specific country, I can do countries['FR'] which in this case will give me France. But I want to get all countries, and in some cases, their capital or continent. How can I do this?
I found the info here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/countries-list
But I failed to find any help or documentation on what I want
If anyone knows a better way/package that will deliver me all countries with the languages etc, please share

countries is an object, not an array. If you want a list of all, your after.. for (const country of Object.values(countries)) { console.log(country.name) }
eg.


<script type="module">
import {countries} from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/countries-list@3.1.0/+esm';

for (const country of Object.values(countries)) {
  console.log(country.name);
}
</script>




For a more detailed answer, when you call countries['UA'], you are accessing the key-value pair with the key of 'UA', thus returning to you the object that is the value for that key.
...
}
UA: {
    name: 'Ukraine',
    native: 'Україна',
    phone: [380],
    continent: 'EU',
    capital: 'Kyiv',
    currency: ['UAH'],
    languages: ['uk'],
  },
US: {
...

Your for loop declares i to be equal to 1, and increment each iteration. There is no key in the table for 1.  This would work if this was an array, where you could access each element by the index number, (which is why we name it i usually).
Iterating through an object it is actually quite similar to an array though. Using the Object.entries(countries) method, you can pass your object and it will return an array of a its own enumerable string-keyed property key-value pairs.
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(countries)) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${value}`); // UA: {...}
}

Object.entries() documentation
The reason that countries.map() doesn't work here is because the map method belongs to arrays and not objects.
You can still manually access the values in the same way however. For example:
countries['FR']['languages']

would return ['French']
Hope this helps!

Use a for..in statement like:
for (let country in countries) 
{ 
  console.log(country);
}

